# Why "ǃ".isalpha() is True but "!".isalpha() is False?

Tags: python, unicode, isalpha

I have just found this strange behaviour parsing data from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

```
"ǃ".isalpha() # returns True
"!".isalpha() # returns False
```

Apparently, the two exclamation marks are different:

```
In [62]: hex(ord("ǃ"))                                                          
Out[62]: '0x1c3'

In [63]: hex(ord("!"))                                                          
Out[63]: '0x21'
```

Just wondering is there a way to prevent this to happen? What is the origin of this behaviour?

Comment: are they different?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I undestand this. But I think this is quite a strange behaviour... You would not expect ! to be an alpha

Comment: ```>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category("ǃ") # 'Lo'
>>> unicodedata.category("!") # 'Po'```

Comment: so all questions should go to the organisation behind Unicode I guess

Comment: Have a look as https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+01C3 . You see it is categorized as "Other Letter".

Comment: `ǃ` is part of an alphabet, not an exclamation mark. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_click

Comment: @blhsing thanks I think this is the answer to my question please formalize it in an answer

Comment: You should go find some recordings of how this is pronounced – it's quite amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check characters in [Unicode Database](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html). The *exclamation-like* `ǃ` (`\u1c3`) is a letter:

```
import unicodedata
for c in "!ǃ":
    print(c,'{:04x}'.format(ord(c)),unicodedata.category(c), unicodedata.name(c))
```

> ```
> ! 0021 Po EXCLAMATION MARK
> ǃ 01c3 Lo LATIN LETTER RETROFLEX CLICK
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

[`str.isalpha()`](http://str.isalpha()%C2%B6%20Return%20True%20if%20all%20characters%20in%20the%20string%20are%20alphabetic%20and%20there%20is%20at%20least%20one%20character,%20False%20otherwise.%20Alphabetic%20characters%20are%20those%20characters%20defined%20in%20the%20Unicode%20character%20database%20as%20%E2%80%9CLetter%E2%80%9D,%20i.e.,%20those%20with%20general%20category%20property%20being%20one%20of%20%E2%80%9CLm%E2%80%9D,%20%E2%80%9CLt%E2%80%9D,%20%E2%80%9CLu%E2%80%9D,%20%E2%80%9CLl%E2%80%9D,%20or%20%E2%80%9CLo%E2%80%9D.%20Note%20that%20this%20is%20different%20from%20the%20%E2%80%9CAlphabetic%E2%80%9D%20property%20defined%20in%20the%20Unicode%20Standard.)

> Return True if all characters in the string are
> alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise.
> **Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode**
> **character database as “Letter”,** i.e., those with general category
> property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this
> is different from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode
> Standard.

It means the utf character you are using is defined as letter in the utf database.

```
>>> ord("ǃ")
   451
```

Looking at [Wikipedia List of UTF characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), the character `ǃ` falls under the [Latin Extended B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-B), and that's why `isalpha` returns `True`